# List of recent "Responses" showing weird text-folding

Tags: bug, profile-page

I recently noticed that, in the "Responses" tab of my "Stack Overflow Meta" profile page, the "Nick Names" column text is folding in a very weird way:

[image]

I cannot reproduce this on the main SO site, nor on any of the other sites I'm registered but there seems to be something similar happening on the main SE Meta sute.

<sup>*(Could this be because of the nature of the source of the most recent response?)*</sup>